# Deny direct access to sitemap.xml (Allow only search bots)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, bots, sitemap, apache2.4

I am on Apache 2.4 and need to restrict direct access to sitemap_index.xml from users with allowing only known bots to access the sitemap, Could you please help me do this with some .htaccess rule?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a rule that blocks access to the sitemap based on the user agent being used, of course this is not very secure since a user always could set the user agent to something else, but this might work for your specific case:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Check so we have a user-agent equal to 'googlebot'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !googlebot$ [NC]
# If the user-agent is not correct we return a 403: Forbidden
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml - [F,L]
```

You can simply change the condition above to include what ever user-agent(s) you would like to include e.g:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(googlebot|spider|foo)$ [NC]
```

The above would allow requests with user-agent set to either googlebot, spider or foo to access the sitemap.xml file.